# How do I remove the window manager of a single application, or open it with no window managment?

Tags: xubuntu, python, window-manager

I need to open a window without it being managed by the window manager, while the other windows on my screen continue to be managed by the window manager, how do I do this?

P.S.

I'm willing to edit the application source code if that's the only way, it's written in python using [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).

Comment: Well I guess I'm actually referring to "decorations" and not the WM, I just want the top bar and borders off of my window so it's just a rectangle with an app drawn inside it, so how do I turn off decorations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DKBose suggestion that I needed to disable "decorations" and not the WM lead me to adding this to my app:

```
window = pyglet.window.Window(1920, 90, style=pyglet.window.Window.WINDOW_STYLE_BORDERLESS)
```

Which solved my problem.